# There exists a unique 4-regular graph with 9 vertices with independence polynomial 1+9x+18x^2+9x^3.

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to prove that there exists only one $4$-regular connected graph with $9$ vertices with independence polynomial $1+9x+18x^2+9x^3$.Now, I am done with existence and also shown each vertex will contribute $3$, $3$-independent sets only.

[image]

I am stuck now to show that if there exists another such graph then it will be isomorphic to the obtained graph.

How should I proceed?

Comment: What is the graph you already have?

Comment: I am not able to upload the graph but its structure is described below:       Its a C9 cycle with 1,4,7 are adjacent; 2,5,8 are adjacent; 3,6,9 are adjacent.

Comment: I replaced your "black on darkest grey" image with one of a regular nonagram and equilateral triangles inscribed in a circle.  Ignoring the circle it seems to be the graph you found.

Comment: Yes..it's the one..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I ran some code in Maple and your conjecture is true. Of the 2601 connected graphs with that independence polynomial, yours is the only one that is regular. For this small example, exhaustive computer search worked well, but as far as how to proceed for other examples, I would suggest looking at this paper:

https://www.mscs.dal.ca/~hoshino/ipunique.pdf

The graph in question actually appears in Figure 1, it is $C_{9,\{3,4\}}$. I'm not sure what your bigger research question is, but circulant graphs may be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks,but the graph I obtained is C9,{3}.

Comment: Sorry,C9,{1,3}.

Comment: $C_{\{1,3\}}$ is isomorphic to $C_{\{3,4\}$ with the labeling you've indicated the isomorphism is 1 ->1, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 9, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 8, 6 -> 3, 7 -> 7, 8 -> 2, 9 -> 6

Comment: Sorry, that should read $C_{9,\{1,3\}}$ is isomorphic to $C_{9,\{3,4\}}$.

Comment: I am trying to prove another result that no disconnected graph have this independence polynomial.Can you please verify it with Maple code??Thanks.

Comment: Yes I checked for disconnected graphs as well and none have this independence polynomial. This can be shown without a computer as the polynomial is irreducible over the integers, so it can not be expressed as the product of two independence polynomials. The graph data I used is available here, <http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html>, if you want to run some code yourself. You can read these in in Maple as I have or in most computer algebra systems, like Sage for example and compute the independence polynomials. It is a very helpful site.

Comment: Thanks for your help.